# How to remove unwanted white space in CSS

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/38h8acaq/

How do I remove the white space to the left of the first tab and between the tabs and the content? You will see I have inserted a lot of `margin:0px;` lines into the CSS but none of them will remove the whitespace.

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab #3</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">Content tab1</div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">Content tab2</div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab">Content tab3.</div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab">Content tab4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As good practice you should use a CSS reset stylesheet which resets all computed styles. http://cssreset.com/ This will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `padding-left: 0px`? Seems to work here.

Comment: Thank you, I knew It would be something simple!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
.tab-links ul {
   margin: 0px;
}
```

to

```
.tabs ul{
   margin:0px;
}
```

html to explain

```
 <ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a>

    </li>      
</ul>
```

Reason. You selected a `ul` after the `.tab-links ul` so I toke the parent element of the `ul` you need and I used that to select the `ul` you need

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38h8acaq/2/)

Comment: Thank you, I knew It would be something simple!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following css to remove the space from first left tab:

```
.tab-links {
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;
}

.tab-links li:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/38h8acaq/1/

Answer (score 0):

as for your first question

you have a `padding-left:40px` on tab links,

reset it with `.tab-links{padding:0}`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tabs {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
/*----- Tab Links -----*/

/* Clearfix */
 .tab-links:after {
display: block;
clear: both;
content:'';
}
ul.tab-links {
padding: 0;
margin: 0px;
}
.tab-links li {
margin: 0px 5px;
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
.tab-links li:first-child{
 margin-left: 0;
}
.tab-links a {
padding: 9px 15px;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
background: #7FB5DA;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 600;
color: #4c4c4c;
transition: all linear 0.15s;
margin:0px;
}
.tab-links a:hover {
background: #a7cce5;
text-decoration: none;
}
li.active a, li.active a:hover {
background: #da7fca;
color: #4c4c4c;
}
/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
 .tab-content {
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 2px;
background: #ff0005;
}
.tab {
display: none;
margin: 0px;
}
.tab.active {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
<ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab #3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab">Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab">Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</div>
</div>
</div>
```